# How can I show/hide points in OpenGL based on user input?

Tags: c++, opengl

I have a "draw" function which currently just uses an interaction file to draw points based on the left mouse click from the user. The drawing of the points works fine, but I can not figure out how to "hide" the points based on a user command. Currently, I have a menu setup which is activated by a middle mouse click, and one option is to "Show/Hide Control Points", but it will not work.

I am drawing the points as follows:

```
void draw(int mode)
{
unsigned int i;

// The following lines  draw all the points
   glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
   glPointSize(5.0);
   glBegin(GL_POINTS);
   for (i=0; i<C->B.size(); i++)
   glVertex2f(C->B[i].x, C->B[i].y);
   glEnd();
}
```

Initially, I had tried to define an integer called `showCtrlPts`, which gloablly was set equal to 1. I set up a selectMessage function, which treated each selection from the middle button menu as a case. For the show/hide points case, I simply changed the value of the showCtrlPts integer and thought that that would do it (see below). Only it didn't work and now I'm somewhat lost as to how to proceed.

```
void selectMessage(int msg)
{
    switch (msg) {
    case 1:
        if (!C->B.empty())
            C->B.clear();
        glutPostRedisplay();
        break;
    case 2:
        glutPositionWindow(50, 50);
        glutReshapeWindow(600, 400);
        break;
    case 3:
        glutFullScreen();
        break;
    case 4:
        if (showCtrlPts == 1)
        {
            showCtrlPts = 0;
            glColor3f(0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
        }
         if (showCtrlPts != 1)
        {
            showCtrlPts = 1;
            glColor3f(0.0, 1.0, 1.0);
        }
       break;
  case 10:
      exit(0);
      break;
  default:
      break;
      }
  glutPostRedisplay();
}
```

Comment: The `showCtrlPts` approach is the right way to go. Show how you used this variable.

Comment: I have shown it in the code above, under `case 4`. I obviously am missing something but I haven't yet figured out what that something is.

Comment: warning: [you're trying to learn a very outdated version of OpenGL](https://kos.gd/posts/dont-use-old-opengl/)

Answer (score 0):

In function `void draw(int mode)`
comment line `glColor3f (0.0, 1.0, 1.0);`